# Xamarin Android NotificationCompat not displaying and no errors

Tags: android, forms, firebase, xamarin

Working with Xamarin Forms, currently just the Android Platform and I'm trying to get Notifications to work via Azure and Firebase. In it's current state, the notification is received and has content so it isn't null, it's just the basic one it says "Azure test notification". However, I've been Googling all day and for some reason I cannot find the answer to my question: the notification will not display and has no errors, it just steps over the code and doesn't do anything.

Creating the channel in MainActivity (I did this in here because docs.microsoft said to)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
            // support library). There is no need to create a notification
            // channel on older versions of Android.
            return;
        }

        var name = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.AppName);
        var description = GetString(Resource.String.Description);
        var channel = new NotificationChannel("4867453", name, NotificationImportance.Default)
        {
            Description = description
        };

        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
```

And in my separate service class I have

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
    var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Channel_ID)
                .SetContentTitle("Test Message")
                .SetContentText(messageBody)
                .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    var notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
    notificationManager.Notify(Notification_ID, notification.Build());
```

Some of this, mainly the Intent stuff, is something that I found on Microsoft Docs and hasn't made a difference to the app working or not at all, I have removed it before to test but it made no difference.

I'm probably doing something a little stupid if I'm being honest, however, if anyone can shed some light upon my issue I'd be very grateful. Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue when I started using Android 9(Pie).

It turns out in Android 9.0 they deprecated the [Apache HTTP Client](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#apache-p) which the [NotificationHubs Bindings nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.Android) package depends on.

Per their documentation:

> To continue using the Apache HTTP client, apps that target Android 9
> and above can add the following to their AndroidManifest.xml:
>
> `<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>`

After I added this, my notifications started working again.

There does seem to be a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs/issues/46) that says it fixed but their nuget package seems really out of date.

Comment: Regret to inform it didn't make a difference, I've added that line into my AndroidManifest.xml and it didn't seem to change anything. I've stepped over the code and watched it run over the NotificationCompat lines where it creates the Notification and actually attempts to display it, still nothing. Any other ideas would be much appreciated!